# US National Grid (USNG) map service?

Tags: web-service

Anyone know of a map service (WMS, WFS, Esri, other) for the US National Grid?

Comment: removed gis tag; it's "meta" for this site: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NGA produced [an accessible USNG WMS](http://egeoint.nrlssc.navy.mil/arcgis/rest/services/usng/usng/MapServer) which should fit the bill. You also might consider downloading [USNG shapefiles](http://mississippi.deltastate.edu/data/) ([webmap](http://cleveland.deltastate.edu/usng/)) for your area of interest.

Comment: Thanks, this is it!  Your first link is the web service I've been looking for.  While I wish Honolulu was one of the 22 cities covered down to 100m grids, it's great to be able to show USNG down to 1k for anywhere in Hawaii. I've made a quick mashup to illustrate at: http://bit.ly/aXB8kl  And of course the web service covers all the US, not just Hawaii.

Answer (score 1):

We've been doing it internally using JavaScript. Wherever a person clicks on a map and we return the USNG coordinate e.g.  10S EG 98025 23179. So you can't actually view the USNG grid, but you can still at least see the grid value. If you'd like the code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the USNG on Google Map?
http://dhost.info/usngweb/

You can also look at www.fgdc.gov/usng

If no web service is available, one option would be to host your own WFS/WMS service for the data for your internal use.

~SRG

Comment: Thanks for another excellent example of what I'm looking for, except again, I need it as a web service.  This example uses Javascript to draw the grid lines.  Here's a link where you can find links to the code and other useful info: http://bit.ly/bBC1pW  Still looking for that web service...  (btw: click the "information about this application..." in the link provided by SRG for some really useful info on USNG)

Comment: If no web service is available, one option would be to host your own WFS/WMS service for the data for your internal use.

Answer (score 0):

http://esri-flex.s3.amazonaws.com/flexviewer/index.html
this site may be consuming a service but I don't know...

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for, except I need it as a webservice I can mashup. This beautiful example is a widget that works with the Esri Flex API so it'd be perfect if I were developing a Flex app. Here's a link to the widget and code for anyone interested: http://bit.ly/9HjKOG Still looking for that web service... (btw: after you click the link from amgreiner - go to the tools menu and click US National Grid)